# Sort emails by size in a conversation view

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Usually I use a conversation view option for my Inbox folder on an Exchange server sorted by 'received' field. When conversation isn't expanded Outlook shows a total size of the whole email thread when the size column is visible in the grid. It calculates the sum of each email from the thread, when the conversation is expanded - the same size column shows a size of each email.

I would like to clean my mailbox from useless huge email threads that consume dozens or hundreds of MBs, however each email from such treads usually isn't the big one. Clean up feature isn't so useful here.

My assumption is that it will be enough to create a custom view with grouping by conversation and sorting by size - is a bad one because Outlook makes grouping instead of showing in a conversation view - size of the thread isn't visible for a group as well as any other columns.
Since my account have any administrative privileges - I won't be able to use any plug-in for the task.

Do I understand correctly, that conversation view isn't configurable in Outlook 2016 at all?

Desired result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDiCb.png

Default view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/apZFC.png

This is what I usually get (wrong):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6LGv.png

Comment: I've added a URLs to a tiny screenshots

Comment: I have thousands of emails (this is almost impossible to clean up) and none of them are bigger than couple of MBs. Even after Outlook Clean-Up feature I see that there are present some long email conversations that are seems to be useless for me but due to a huge number of emails in such conversations - the size of a conversation hits dozens or even hundreds of MBs.

Comment: Unfortunately PST files on thick clients are prohibited by my employer and Exchange mailbox is limited to 5 GBs while I really have to refer to emails even 5 years ago. Previously PST option was absolutely fine but since I receive hundreds of emails every day - storage is always a problem.